# How to implement implicit Runge-kutta (RK-4) method for a system of non-linear differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, runge-kutta-methods

I am trying to solve a set of non-linear ode's using an implicit RK-4 method. I have already solved this problem using a backward euler's method.

$$ \frac{dy_i}{dt} = a_i*y_{i-1} -  b_i*y_i + c_i*y_{i+1} , 1<i<n $$
$$ y_1 = d$$
$$ y_n = 0$$

While solving the above system of differential equation using the implicit method, I had solved for the solution for future time-step $l+1$ by computing $\frac{dy_i}{dt}^{l+1}$ and in variable form and substituting in the equation

$$ y_{i}^{l+1} = y_{i}^{l} + \delta_t*\frac{dy_i}{dt}^{l+1}$$

by get a tri-diagonal matrix, and after that used TDMA algorithm (forward elimination and back substitution) to get the solution $y_{i}^{l+1}$.

example for $i =2$ ; $ y_{2}^{l+1} = y_{2}^{l} +  a_1*y_{1}^{l+1} -  b_1*y_{2}^{l+1} + c_1*y_{3}^{l+1} $ . Now  $y_{2}^{l+1} ( 1 + b_1) - a_1*y_{1}^{l+1} - c_1*y_{3}^{l+1}  = y_{2}^{l} $

In this when we write all the equations for $2$ to $(n-1)$ , we get a system of equations with tri-diagonal arrangement of unknown variables.

---

Now, I want to implement a RK-4 method for solving this system. Where I will have to compute $\frac{dy_i}{dt}$ at various time-steps like,

$$ y_{i}^{l+1} = y_{i}^{l} + \delta_i *(\frac{k_1}{6} + \frac{k_2}{3} + \frac{k_3}{3} + \frac{k_4}{6}) $$

where, $k_1 = \frac{dy_i}{dt}^{l}$ , $k_2 = \frac{dy_i}{dt}^{l+k_1/2}$ , $k_3 = \frac{dy_i}{dt}^{l+k_2/2}$ , $k_4 = \frac{dy_i}{dt}^{l+k_3}$

But how will I implement the same method in an implicit way, like I had done the backward euler method.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: RK4 is an explicit method, no need to solve linear systems. Just encapsulate the system as $\frac{dy_{1<i<n}}{dt}=F(y_{1<i<n})$ and feed it into any general formulation of the RK4 method. This would be different if you were to use the implicit Gauss or SDIRK methods.

Comment: Or taking the question more literally, please clarify what is your implicit 4th order Runge-Kutta method, do you have a link to a Butcher tableau?

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for your reply! Actually I want to ask the same thing, is it that RK-4 can't be implemented as implicit method? 

As far as I have thought about it, we can only implement the backward Euler method for an implicit solution. as when we compute the slope $\frac{dy}{dt}^{l+1}$, we already know the predicted $y^{l+1}$. So we can't go anywhere from there! Even if we take a value at {l+1/2} and further go on to {l+1} time, it does not mean anything. It is same as taking timestep as half of the original.

Am I thinking in the right direction?

Comment: No, classical RK4 is always an explicit method. One could think of the first 3 stages as a fixed predictor-corrector-corrector "loop" for the midpoint method, but that was not the guiding principle in its construction. If you go to implicit methods, then you get increased order already with fewer stages. The 2-stage Gauss method has order 4.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot. I have already implemented RK-4 explicit method and backward euler implicit method for my problem. It is just that we are looking for a better implicit method? I tried looking for the 2-stage gauss method, but couldn't find it on the internet! Can you please suggest me some documents/ articles? Also I have thought about the implicit midpoint method mylself. My thought are, taking finding $y^{l+1/2} $ and $\frac{dy}{dt}^{l+1/2}$ . after that finding $y^{l+1}$ and $\frac{dy}{dt}^{l+1}$ both in an implicit way. (1/2)

Comment: And the 3rd step, taking the slope as $ \frac{dy}{dt}^{new} = \frac{1}{2} ( \frac{dy}{dt}^{l+1/2} + \frac{dy}{dt}^{l+1}) $ and now computing $ y^{l+1} = y^{l} + \delta_t \frac{dy}{dt}^{new} $ . In my opinion it will give a better prediction of the slope, although I haven't calculated the order of this method! .. (2/2)

Comment: The midpoint method can be implemented as the combination of an implicit and an explicit Euler step of half the step size. Both have errors in opposite directions that cancel in this combination. The ability to "intuitively" construct methods stops at order 2, for all higher order methods one needs to solve the order conditions or use the established Butcher tableaus. For a short overview see the slides https://www.math.auckland.ac.nz/~butcher/ODE-book-2008/Tutorials/, the connected book or the books of Hairer et al and Shampine.

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot! Yes, true I think the intuitive creation stops at order 2. Next up, we require strategic combination of series expansion of the derivatives. I will see the tutorial for help! Can you also tell me the state of the art or the scope of learning these methods? Where all I may use these? Currently I am using these to solve a precipitate evolution problem using a grouping method.

Comment: I think the Hairer books are still quite valid for learning. I see the evolution as low-order fixed-step methods for scalar problems, up to RK4, then the same for systems of ODE. Then explicit higher order methods with step-size control. Implicit methods stepping from fixed-point iteration to Newton-like iterations. Using diagonally implicit methods (DIRK and SDIRK) for efficiency. Use of (sparse) linear algebra libraries for large systems. Using compartementalized models with different time scales in the integration, that is, time is the same, step size scales vary.